# Can spam bots trigger mouseenter or hover events?

Tags: jquery, html, spam-prevention

I'm trying to add my email address to my homepage so that spam bots can't see it. Somewhere on stackoverflow I found the solution to write the address reverse:

```
<span class="reverse">moc.liam@esrever</span>
<style>
.reverse {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
</style>
```

But so that users still can interact with a mailto-link I've got the following code:

```
<a href="moc.liam@esrever:otliam" class="reverse"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a>
<script>
    $('body').on('mouseenter', '.reverse', function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').split('').reverse().join(''));
    });
    $('body').on('mouseleave', '.reverse', function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').split('').reverse().join(''));
    });
</script>
```

Is this a secure method to hide your email address to spam bots or do they trigger the mouseenter event as well?

Comment: He is hiding it... He reversed the mail adres, they can't read reversed mail adresses.

Comment: Yeah, fair comment @Johan, will retract my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "generic" spambot that triggered events in order to harvest email addresses would have to feed the page into basically a headless browser, somehow determine what might be JS-obfuscated email content and then blindly try to emulate the user interaction that deobfuscates the interesting data.

This is an enormous amount of work for possibly no benefit and no spammer would ever consider doing it.

What they *would* do instead if they were *really* interested in harvesting your site is figure out how your protection works (hey, it's just written in reverse) and just special-case the spambot to unscramble the data manually.

This type of protection scheme should be more than enough as long as you are too small to be worth targeting, but the downside is that website visitors that do not use JavaScript are going to have a hard time.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I'm just trying to hide my email from generic spam bots, because my site only shows one email address. So it wouldn't be profitable to write a special spam bot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Spam bots will in general only read the page markup and look for email links or email addresses that match a certain pattern. So your method will probably throw of the majority of them - the ones that will (incorrectly) see `moc.liam@esrever` as the email address.

However, just as a crawler knows that an email link starts with `mailto:`, it could also know that a reversed email link ends with `:otliam`. If the creator of the crawler finds the suggestion to reverse the email address, like you did, they'll just modify the bot to process reversed addresses as well.

The best protection is good email spam detection, or an HTML form that uses a [Captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) or similar.

Comment: sure it's not that hard to reverse, but how many spambot writers are going to spend time actually doing that?

Comment: I would if I wrote spam bots - like you said it's not very hard and would take less than 5 minutes. If it means I get a few extra email addresses, it's worth doing.

Comment: Well, I could optimize the method by replacing a special character with @.

Comment: @greg84 clearly you're underestimating the amount of data they have to scrape through. If you spent the time to deobfuscate every string that had an @ sign you'd be spending your entire life doing that, or you could spend your time collecting unobfuscated emails that you can quickly validate. 

From a spammers perspective it is not worth the time when there are plenty more low hanging fruit.

Comment: You could also base64 encode it, or encrypt it and do an HTTPS request to decrypt the value using a cookie as a public key - both of which are over the top. What you're doing now will evade *most*, but just make it as hard as possible for people to scrape your email address of the page without having to do too much work.